# How to save a .txt/.csv in internal storage ? Delphi

Tags: android, delphi

How do I create a folder and store files in the internal Android storage with DELPHI?
(with internal storage I mean, when you go in the settings on android -> storage -> explore, there have "facebook", "whatsapp", "downloads" and any other app you have downloaded)

I have a variable that stores a lot of data separated by ";" and "/ n" for wrapping lines, I need to store this in a .CSV file (or .TXT) and save it inside some folder inside the internal storage .. Looking on the internet I found only external storage .. Does anyone know how I can do this ?

Note: If by chance it is better to create the .csv file through a vector (not a variable), I can modify my code without problems

Comment: Obs: ONLY Android

Comment: See [Standard RTL Path Functions across the Supported Target Platforms](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Standard_RTL_Path_Functions_across_the_Supported_Target_Platforms). `System.SysUtils.GetHomePath()`, `System.IOUtils.TPath.GetHomePath()`, and `System.IOUtils.TPath.GetDocumentsPath()` give you a path to internal storage.

Comment: But how i create a .txt file and new folder in the "System.IOUtils.TPath.GetDocumentsPath()" ?

Comment: The same way you create any folder/file on any platform - using things like `SysUtils.CreateDir()`, `SysUtils.ForceDirectories()`, `System.IOUtils.TDirectory`, `AssignFile()`, `TFileStream`, `System.IOUtils.TFile`, etc. `System.IOUtils.TPath` just helps you find OS folder paths, but what you do with them is up to you. `var FileName: string := TPath.Combine(TPath.GetDocumentsPath, 'SubFolder' + PathDelim + 'file.txt'); use FileName as needed...`